# ASP.NET Core 6 authorization ClaimTypes.Role not authorizing the right roles

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, swagger, asp.net-authorization

I'm quite new to this and still learning and have looked up the Microsoft documentations, but to no avail. I'm currently trying to authorize the `ClaimTypes.Role` of `Author`, however, when tested with other roles, it seems to still bypass the authorization. Any advice helps!

I have added `app.UseAuthentication()` before `app.useAuthorization()`.

This application was also created using Swagger and SwaggerUI, but I did not seem to be able to find people who have an issue with this while using Swagger.

Dependencies:

- Swashbuckle.AspNetCore v6.2.3
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer v6.0.21

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AuthorOnly", policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Author"));
});
```

```
[HttpPost, Authorize(Policy = "AuthorOnly")]
public IActionResult AddTutorial(Tutorial tutorial)
{
    var userID = GetUserID();
    var now = DateTime.Now;

    var myTutorial = new Tutorial()
            {
                Title = tutorial.Title.Trim(),
                Description = tutorial.Description.Trim(),
                CreatedAt = now,
                UpdatedAt = now,
                UserID = userID,
            };

    context.Tutorials.Add(myTutorial);
    context.SaveChanges();

    return Ok(myTutorial); // returns a 200 status code
}
```

This is how the token is made, if relevant:

```
private string CreateToken(User user)
{
    string secret = configuration.GetValue<string>("Authentication:Secret");
    int tokenExpiresDays = configuration.GetValue<int>("Authentication:TokenExpiresDays");

    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secret);

    // What kind of information is stored in the token 
    // Information that is most usually used for authentication/identification
    // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claim?view=net-7.0 (For claims understanding)
    var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                // Subject is the entity (usually a user requesting access to a resource)
                // ClaimsIdentity is a collection of claims that describe the properties and attributes of the subject
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[] 
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString()),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Name),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, user.UserRole)
                }),
                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(tokenExpiresDays),
                // Specifies the signing key, signing key identifier, and security algorithms to generate a digital signature for SamlAssertion
                SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
            };

    var securityToken = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
    string token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(securityToken);

    return token;
}
```

**Edit:**

This is the authentication scheme:

```
var secret = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("Authentication:Secret");
builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secret)
            ),
        };
    });
```

When logged in as `GenericUser` and a user role of `User`, I am still able to post data despite the authentication needing the user role of `Author`. In the token, the ClaimTypes.Role is also saved as `User`.
The user data:

```
email: "user@email.com"
id: 2
name: "GenericUser"
userRole: "User"
```

The author role:

```
email: "author@email.com"
id: 1
name: "GenericAuthor"
userRole: "Author"
```

Comment: Hi,@Stried,could you share a minimal example that could reproduce the  issue? which scheme is the default authentication scheme is your app?

Comment: Hello @RuikaiFeng, I've added the information in the edit of the post near the bottom, I hope it helps.

Comment: The issue still counldn't be reproduced ,would you mind upload the minimal  example that could repo?

Comment: try this: `policy.RequireClaim("Author")`. that being said, is there any specific reason you are trying to implement policy-based authorization? why not simply implement RBAC? it is very rare for an application to need policy-based access control, and from what I can see, you just need to verify the existence of a claim, which RBAC can do much more easily.

Comment: @Stried 1. If the last provided examples (user data and author data) are claims from `ClaimsPrincipal` probably from (`HttpContext.User`), then something is wrong. Because if you use `ClaimTypes.Role`, the value should be different than `userRole`. Also, instead of using `RequireClaim` you can use `RequireRole`, but it probably won't fix your problem. 2. You can just use `[Authorize(Roles = "Author")]`, instead of creating policy.